# Figure out image sizes when taking a web scrape

Tags: asp.net, image, scrape

I have developed almost all the functionality for having a preview of a web-page, just like facebook does. I use .net hhtprequest and then Html Agility Pack to parse the html and get the nodes and everything. But when it comes to finding the images that are larger than say 100pixels, I try to get the width attribute of image tag, if not i get the style attribute and find the width property, but sometimes the width comes from a css class and other times there is no width information. How can I get my server to load the images and find it out. But that will also cause a lot of load on the server, but any leads will be greatly appreciated. Thx in advance

Comment: Why do you need the width if you are going to display the image anyway? If the dimensions are not specified the image will display as full size.

Comment: I will not display it as full size, process it into a thumbnail. The width being more than 100px will mean that it is a relevant image, not an advertisement and so on ... hopefully :)

Answer (score 2):

You can load image from URL:

```
  int width = 0;
  int height = 0;

  WebClient client = new WebClient();

  using(Stream stream = client.OpenRead(imageUrl))
  using(Image image = Image.FromStream(stream))
  {
    width = image.Width;
    height = image.Height;
  }
```

The downfall being that you are making an additional HTTP request for every image you encounter that doesn't have dimensions set in HTML or CSS.

Comment: even if the dimensions are set in html/css, they may be wrong. Think about a noob developer setting the width of a 10 px image to 100 pixels.. I should use this and ignore all the info in the markup i think. Am i wrong?

Comment: That would definitely offer better accuracy.